# How can I quote text in a search regex?

Tags: regular-expression, search

I want to yank text from a window and search for it but the text contains characters not interpreted literally by the search command, e.g. a file path. Is there an easy way I can quote the yanked text when entering the search command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for literal text by using the `\V` [modifier](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#/%5CV), which means **very nomagic** after which only the backslash keeps it special meaning.

In my .vimrc I have this command to search for text literally:

`:com! -nargs=1 Search :let @/='\V'.escape(<q-args>, '\\')| norm! n`

Comment: From Vim help:

> Use of "\V" means that in the pattern after it only the backslash and the
terminating character (/ or ?) has a special meaning.  "very nomagic"

Comment: I am not sure, what you are trying to tell me, but note, that the terminating character refers to the usage of **/** and **?** normal mode commands, which in my example I do not use, so there is no need to escape them.

Comment: I didn't realize that "terminating character" referred to the normal mode command character.

Answer (score 4):

There is unfortunately no option to have search input interpreted as raw text.

There is something close to it though: the `nomagic` option causes most characters (but not all) to be interpreted literally.

To activate `nomagic` for a single search, prefix the search pattern with `\M`.

You can also activate `nomagic` globally (`:set nomagic`). Vim's help warns that this might break plugins (though many plugin writers take care to explicitly set the desired magic mode for their patterns).

The following characters still won't be interpreted literally in nomagic mode and will need to be escaped with a `\` (backslash):

- `$` end of line
- `\` escape character
- `/` or `?` (depending on whether you are searching forward or backward) or any other separator that you have chosen if you are searching on the command line

See `:h nomagic` or `:h \m`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Tho prefixing the search pattern `\V` ("very nomagic") seems better than `\M` for this.

Comment: Indeed, \V frees up `$` (no other difference though it seems).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to 'cheat', particularly for paths or other text containing forward slashes, is to use `?` instead of `/`.

Source:

- [Search without need to escape slash | Vim Tips Wiki | Fandom powered by Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_without_need_to_escape_slash)